# Updating a model class in React JS during development seems to immediately erase any changes to data

Tags: reactjs

So, I like to use a model class with dummy data just cached (not persistent) during development. I'm having a component make changes to the model.js class's data based on form data entered and submitted by the user (I call preventDefault() on submission). Everything seems to be fine except that the new data seems to be deleted just after adding them to model.js. I have verified this using breakpoints and console.log(). The whole webpage seems to be refreshing and IDK why. I'm not even calling setState() as of now.

Edit: to be clear, the model class at the bottom of the code is not maintaining updates with it's data. I haven't worried about rerendering the Component using it as its state yet.

```
    class ManageFinances extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            model: new FinancesModel(),
          }
    
          this.addFinanceItem = this.addFinanceItem.bind(this);
        }
    
        getFinanceItemsView(financeItems) {
          ... /*not important*/
        }
    
        // The callback that seems to be giving me issues
        addFinanceItem(name, amount, type) {
          this.state.model.addMonthlyFinanceItem(name, amount, type)
          console.log(this.state);
          //this.setState();
        }
    
        render() {
          const monthlyFinanceItems = this.state.model.getMonthlyFinanceItems();
          const monthlyFinanceItemsView = this.getFinanceItemsView(monthlyFinanceItems);
          // const difference = monthlyIncome - monthlyExpenses.reduce((x, a) => x + a);
          
          return (
            <div className="home">
              <div className="month-container">
                <input type="month" className="month-selector"></input>
              </div>
              <div className="home-main">
                <div className="row">
                  <FinanceItemForm submitCallback={this.addFinanceItem} /> // Passed to the form as a prop
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <table className="finance-table">
                    <colgroup>
                      <col className="finance-name-column"></col>
                      <col className="finance-amount-column"></col>
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                      {monthlyFinanceItemsView[0]}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div className="column">
                    {monthlyFinanceItemsView[1]}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
       }
    }
    
    // The component with the form
    class FinanceItemForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                type: 'Income',
                name: '',
                amount: 0.00,
            }
    
            this.handleChangeType = this.handleChangeType.bind(this);
            this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
            this.handleChangeAmount = this.handleChangeAmount.bind(this);
        }
    
        handleChangeType (event) {
            this.setState({
                type: event.target.value,
            });
        }
    
        handleChangeName (event) {
            this.setState({
                name: event.target.value,
            });
        }
    
        handleChangeAmount (event) {
            this.setState({
                amount: event.target.value,
            });
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <form 
                    className="finance-item-form" 
                    onSubmit={(event) => {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.props.submitCallback(this.state.name, 
                                                  this.state.amount, 
                                                  this.state.type)
                    }}
                >
                    <div className="input-container">
                        <div className="input-row1">
                            <select onChange={this.handleChangeType}>
                                <option>Income</option>
                                <option>Expense</option>
                            </select>
                            <div className="label-and-field">
                                <label htmlFor="item-name">Enter Name:</label>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    name="item-name" 
                                    maxLength="50" 
                                    onChange={this.handleChangeName}
                                ></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-row2">
                            <div className="label-and-field">
                                <label htmlFor="item-amount">Enter Amount:</label>
                                <input 
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="item-amount" 
                                    step=".01" 
                                    min="0.00" 
                                    onChange={this.handleChangeAmount}
                                ></input>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }

// The dummy model class for development
class FinancesModel {
    constructor() {
        this.financeItems = [
            ['Day Job', 5145, 92, 'Income'],
            ['Netflix', 25, 67, 'Expense'],
            ['Hidive', 5, 98, 'Expense'],
            ['Voice Acting Royalties', 20, 0, 'Income'],
            ['Student Loans', 400, 2, 'Expense'],
            ['Rent', 900, 0, 'Expense'],
            ['5th Place at Professional Smash Bros Tournament HD', 40, 2, 'Income'],
        ];
    }

    addMonthlyFinanceItem(name, amount, type) {
        const dollars = Math.floor(amount);
        const cents = amount - dollars;
        const financeItem = [name, dollars, cents, type];
        this.financeItems.push(financeItem);
    }

    getMonthlyFinanceItems() {
        return this.financeItems.slice();
    }

    getFinanceItemName(financeItem) {
        return financeItem[0];
    }

    getFinanceItemAmount(financeItem) {
        const dollars = financeItem[1];
        const cents = financeItem[2] / 100;
        return dollars + cents;
    }

    getFinanceItemAmountPrettyString(financeItem) {
        const dollars = financeItem[1];
        const cents = financeItem[2];
        const str = cents < 10 ? '0' + cents : cents;
        return '$' + dollars + '.' + str;
    }

    getFinanceItemType(financeItem) {
        return financeItem[3];
    }

    getFinanceItemCount() {
        return this.monthlyIncomes.length + this.financeItems.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show some code, it's very hard to help otherwise.

Comment: K. I added the relevant code.

Comment: Why are you mutating the state ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize using immutable data is always preferred. This model class is just basically a temporary placeholder for a database anyway. I'm not sure how that's relevant to the issue I'm having though. Why not mutate it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because the component is not aware that the state has changed, if you mutate it in place.

Comment: I understand that. I'm not trying to make the component rerender itself yet, as stated in my OP, I'm not even worrying about setState yet. I need to get past the issue I described first. Unless there is some connection between the two that you aren't explaining.

Comment: Your code, as posted, works fine. See https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-noether-glcpl?file=/src/App.js the problem you describe, though, sounds like the form is actually submitted, or perhaps something higher in the component hierarchy gets re-mounted

Comment: Thanks for testing. Yeah that's strange... All I have higher up the tree is a navbar and some routes (this being one of the routes)... Weird... I'll mark this answered for now I guess since I don't have time to post more code rn.

Comment: Okay, so I switched from using a class as my model to a node.js module instead and it works now... Darn my lack of webdev skills. Though I still find the behavior of react weird in this case. I'll probably just have to get used to it.